# Fetch throws “Network request failed” with ip number set

Tags: react-native, expo

I recently had to update expo and consequently some libraries due to the new version. The app was able to fetch by HTTP. But now after trying several ways, I decide to go HTTPS.

Now the server is ready and returns the values on Postman and browser (browser shows a certificate warning but still shows the data after the acceptation of "not secure connection).

I also checked all the posts related to "not using 'localhost' but the actual ip", that's not the issue. I have no idea how to handle this situation.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, Text, View, Keyboard } from "react-native";
import MyToast from "./MyToast";

const Consulta = async (valor, setShowPrice, setMakingConsulta, setController, setSignal, setShowAbortButton) => {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const signal = controller.signal;

  if (signal.aborted) {
    console.log("Consulta cancelada");
  }

  setController(controller);
  setSignal(signal);

  if (valor === "" || !valor) {
    MyToast("Escribe algún valor para realizar la búsqueda.", 5);
    return;
  }
  Keyboard.dismiss();
  setMakingConsulta(true);
  setShowAbortButton(true);
 
  const localUrl = `https://192.168.1.125:9999/v/${valor}`;

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(localUrl, {
        signal: signal,
      });

      if (!response?.ok) {
        console.log("Detalles de la respuesta con error:", response);
        throw new Error("Respuesta con error: " + response?.statusText);
      }

      if (!response) {
        console.log("Detalles del error de la respuesta:", response);
        throw new Error("Error de respuesta: " + response?.statusText || "No hay respuesta del servidor.");
      }

      setShowAbortButton(false);
      const data = await response.json();

      if (!Array.isArray(data) || data.length === 0) {
        throw new Error(`No hay datos con ${valor}`);
      }

      const resultado = duplicarArticulos(data);
      resultado.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.multicodigo_codigo) {
          if (a.multicodigo_codigo === valor) return -1;
        } else {
          if (a.cod_articulo === valor) return -1;
        }
        if (b.multicodigo_codigo) {
          if (b.multicodigo_codigo === valor) return 1;
        } else {
          if (b.cod_articulo === valor) return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      });

      setShowPrice(resultado);

      Keyboard.dismiss();
    } catch (localError) {
      MyToast("Se produjo un error: " + localError.message, 10, "error");
      console.error("Error en conexión local.", localError);
    } finally {
      setMakingConsulta(false);
    }
  };

  fetchData();

  function duplicarArticulos(data) {
    let articulos = {};
    let resultado = [];

    data.forEach((item) => {
      if (articulos[item.cod_articulo]) {
        if (item.multicodigo_cantidad !== null) {
          articulos[item.cod_articulo].count++;
        }
      } else {
        articulos[item.cod_articulo] = {
          count: item.multicodigo_cantidad !== null ? 1 : 0,
          item: { ...item },
        };
      }
    });

    Object.values(articulos).forEach((articulo) => {
      if (articulo.item.multicodigo_cantidad) {
        let copia = { ...articulo.item };
        copia.multicodigo_cantidad = null;
        copia.multicodigo_codigo = null;
        copia.multicodigo_cantidad_pvp = null;
        copia.multicodigo_cantidad_precio_venta_por = null;
        resultado.push(copia);
      }
    });

    return [...resultado, ...data];
  }
};

export default Consulta;
```

Versions I'm using:

- expo@50.0.7
- npm@10.4.0
- react-native@0.73.4
- react@18.2.0